# Is it possible to make a Box and request user to insert something in the middle?

Tags: c

I wanted to do something like this:

```
+------------------------------------------+
|    Insert your input: ____               |
+------------------------------------------+
```

Where the user would insert the information on the `____` 
The box must be fully built before the user starts to type.

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: @Gavin what would be the other way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but probably not in a very portable way.

You need to figure out howe to control your terminal, so that you can send the necessary control codes to move the cursor as needed to build the box and then move back inside it.

One popular library that does this (and more) is [GNU ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).